# Facebook marketing api access non existing field

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to access campaigns of the facebook account. Using python lib: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk

Receive error: `(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (campaigns) on node type (AdAccount)`

Url: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/{account_id}/campaigns`

Everything worked fine for months. Now, even facebook page for this url is empty: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/campaigns/

Any thoughts, what's the problem?

Comment: did you check out the changelog for deprecations? usually, if something worked, and does not work anymore (especially with that specific error message), it means that facebook changed something. if you cannot find anything in the changelog, you could file a bug.

Comment: we have the same problem using a java client. i tried the same in the graph API explorer and my requests succeeds which makes it even more strange

Comment: @luschn checked already: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11 Path: `{account_id}/campaigns` doesn't seem to be deprecated.

Comment: did you also check older api versions and 90 days deprecations?

Comment: Found this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/707332642990208/ Last working date is the same.

Comment: @luschn checked previous v2.10, same problem. 90 days deprecations - don't understand what you mean. Have any link?

Comment: Problem seems to be with "time_range" param. Works great without this param.

Comment: check out the changelog, there are some deprecations that come in effect 90 days after a new version gets released, and it affects all apps.

Comment: could not find something about that either, so i guess it´s a bug. you should report it and write an answer on your own here, with the working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug.
Reported here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/707332642990208/

Works perfectly without `time_range` param.
So, could be temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a bug or not: facebook does this from time to time and is implementing check routines for parameters - in fact "adaccounts don't have any parameters:[facebook api reference adaccount reading](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account#Reading))

The error you are getting (#100) says "invalid parameter" ([facebook reference adaccount validation rules](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/adaccounts/)), this is, because you may have defined the time_range and you are asking api for campaigns in an adaccount. But: for adaccount edge time_rage parameter is invalid.

**The solution** is to FIRST asking api for `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/{account_id}/campaigns` and after this defining the (time_range) parameter(s) for the insights of your campaign.